# Laravel get image from S3 instead of local

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 app which was previously storing images locally. I have now modified it so that images are stored on an S3 server, I previously retrieved the local images like this...

```
$image_contents = Storage::get('myimages/logos/' . $image->filename);
```

Now I have moved to S3 storage, how can I instead get the image from the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same but you have to put your AWS bucket path:

```
 Storage::disk('s3')->get('AWS_BUCKET_PATH');
```